# Different color on crosstab report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to make a field a certain color based on the difference between its transaction date and today.

I'm using the formula

```
IF DateDiff ('D',{Command.DATE_RECEIVED},CurrentDateTime)>=6
THEN CRRED
ELSE IF DateDiff ('D',{Command.DATE_RECEIVED},CurrentDateTime)<6
THEN CRYELLOW
ELSE IF DateDiff ('D',{Command.DATE_RECEIVED},CurrentDateTime)<3
THEN CRGREEN
```

But everything show's red, even for items received today.

Comment: The formula looks OK. For debugging you can put the DateDiff-part in a separate formula-field and see if you get the expected number of days. This should help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Your formula will fail at second statement, with this logic you can never see GREEN, but check whether you are getting datediff values less than 6